# Angular --base-href React equivalent

Tags: reactjs

I want my site entry point to be like http://localhost:8080/**entrypoint**

In angular, just need to run `ng build --base-href /entrypoint`.

Is there any equivalent parameter for react-scripts build?
If not, how can i achieve it, the base-href edit, as the index.html is generated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve it by setting the `homepage` parameter in your `package.json` to the desired endpoint.

`"homepage": "http://localhost:8080/entrypoint"`

**Edit**

Or you can use the following approach to make all the assets paths relative to the `index.js` file.

According to the [documentation](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/#serving-the-same-build-from-different-paths):

> If you are not using the HTML5 pushState history API or not using client-side routing at all, it is unnecessary to specify the URL from which your app will be served. Instead, you can put this in your package.json:
>
> `"homepage": "."`,
>
> This will make sure that all the asset paths are relative to index.html. You will then be able to move your app from http://mywebsite.com to http://mywebsite.com/relativepath or even http://mywebsite.com/relative/path without having to rebuild it.